# How to replace underscores in a .ttl file only for objects

Tags: replace, notepad++, triplestore, turtle-rdf

I have a file containing RDF triples (subject-predicate-object) in turtle syntax (.ttl file) in which I should replace every _ with a space, but only for triple objects (subjects and predicates must remain the same).
An example is the following (in my case each object is between double quotes "):

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Animalia_(book)> <http://dbpedia.org/property/author> "Graeme_Base" .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Animalia_(book)> <http://dbpedia.org/property/illustrator> "Graeme_Base" .
```

I would like to get:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Animalia_(book)> <http://dbpedia.org/property/author> "Graeme Base" .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Animalia_(book)> <http://dbpedia.org/property/illustrator> "Graeme Base" .
```

What is the easiest and fastest way to achieve this? The files are very large, so I can't replace underscores one at a time. I've tried using regular expressions in Notepad ++ but I don't understand how to exclude subject and predicate.

thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
(?:^<[^\n<>]+>\h+<[^<>\n]+>\h+"|\G(?!^))[^_\n]+\K_(?=[^"\n]*")
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^` Assert start of the string
  - `<[^\n<>]+>\h+<[^<>\n]+>\h+"` Match 2 times an opening-closing angle bracket followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and then match `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^_\n]+\K_` Match 1+ times not an underscore or newline using a negated character class and forget what was matched using `\K`. Then match the underscore.
- `(?=[^"\n]*")` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a closing `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kOsj6d/1)

In the replacement use a space.

Comment: Great regex skills. One thing to keep in mind is that while this will work well if the input data is regular, it is brittle against syntax variations. For example `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Animalia_(book)> <http://dbpedia.org/property/author> "Graeme_Base";\n
                                              <http://dbpedia.org/property/illustrator> "Graeme_Base" .` is legal Turtle syntax which this regex doesn't deal with - and there may be other syntax variations (collections, nested blank nodes, and so on). An alternative approach is to use an RDF library to actually process the data.